# Flink not sinking data to kafka topic

Tags: apache-flink

I have written a flink code which reads a csv file from a folder and sink the data on kafka topic.

Here is my flink job:

```
final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = 
StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

org.apache.flink.core.fs.Path filePath = new           
org.apache.flink.core.fs.Path(feedFileFolder);

RowCsvInputFormat format = new RowCsvInputFormat(filePath, 
FetchTypeInformation.getTypeInformation());


DataStream<Row> inputStream = env.readFile(format, feedFileFolder, 
FileProcessingMode.PROCESS_CONTINUOUSLY,
parseInt(folderLookupTime));


DataStream<String> speStream = inputStream.filter(new FilterFunction<Row> 
().map(new MapFunction<Row, String>() {
@Override
public String map(Row row) {

            ...............
            return resultingJsonString;
        }
    });

Properties props = Producer.getProducerConfig(propertiesFilePath);

speStream.addSink(new FlinkKafkaProducer011(kafkaTopicName, new
    KeyedSerializationSchemaWrapper<>(new SimpleStringSchema()), props,
     FlinkKafkaProducer011.Semantic.EXACTLY_ONCE));
```

**Issue**

When i execute the above flink job from eclipse, it works absolutely fine.
If i place a file of 10 records, i can see on flink UI that flink job sinks 10 records on kafka topic.

```
Name           Bytes received   Records received    Records sent
Source:        0 B              0                   1       
Split Reader   1.12 KB          1                   10      
Sink: Unnamed  1.79 KB          10                  0
```

But when i execute this(as a jar) on flink server, the job is not able to sink the data on kafka topic. Flink UI looks like below :

```
Name           Bytes received   Records received    Records sent
Source:        0 B              0                   1       
Split Reader   616 B            1                   0       
Sink: Unnamed  450 B            0                   0
```

Comment: 1. If the folder is empty and i start the flink job, and then i add a new file in that folder then the above scenario happens.

Comment: 2. If any file is already placed in the folder and then i start the flink job then it works fine and sink the data to kafka.

Comment: Could you check the debug logs of the `TaskManagers` whether the `SplitReader` actually starts reading the splits? If yes, then you should see `Reading splits: <SPLIT>"`.